# What is the best way to display deleted/removed file to viewer?

Tags: usability, accessibility

Scenario: A viewer make some bookmark of document that he can view. 
Then manager archive this document.

Output: The viewer now can't view his document that has been bookmarked.

**File Permission**

*Viewer* - Can view, bookmark file if given permission

*Manager* - Can delete, manage any files

Please see attached example of what I mean

[image]

**How should in-application bookmarks be displayed to the viewer after the things they point to have been deleted by the manager?**

Comment: Sorry can't understand your question. Kindly add more details.

Comment: You have provided a scenario, but not asked anything related to that scenario. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any good solution to your problem will keep the user informed of what is going on. A separate folder that contains archived bookmarks is a good start since it will keep the bookmark list tidy and free of broken links. It is possible, however, that a user might not understand why their link is gone from the list. Therefore I would suggest some sort of informational alert that tells them a bookmark has been moved. Something like this might be advisable:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe2nXE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Here the user has been informed that a resource was deleted, which forced a bookmark to be archived. They can still see the bookmark in the archive folder, but cannot select it, reinforcing the idea that it no longer links to the content it is supposed to.

This kind of solution presumes that managers are not going through and deleting dozens of resources each day. Receiving that many notifications in the bookmarks view would quickly become annoying.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the user will want to "archive" a bookmark that doesn't point to anything.

Comment: Ideally, even when files are deleted, they're not actually removed completely. The idea here is that a file could be brought back, and now the archived link works again. If the user doesn't care about the archive, they can just leave it closed and there's no extra load or effort on their part.

Answer (score 1):

## Informative and in context

There are endless ways to style this depending on the amount of attention you want to draw. Regardless of the prominence, some explanation of why the bookmark is leaving is in order.

[image]

**If this is going to be a frequent occurrence,** I would display this alert once, possibly for a limited amount of time or with an option to dismiss. The next time they sign in, it would be gone.

**If it's likely to be a rare case,** the highlighted entry could be persistent until dismissed / deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross it with a red line like this :

[image]

You can than move it to the bottom of the list or to a separate trash folder.

There are problems with both solutions:

1. Keeping it in the original list conveys the deletion to the viewer but even though the entry was deleted, it will still be there with the rest of the bookmarks. A solution for this is to ask the user to acknowledge the deletion and only after that remove it from the list, or to automatically remove it once it was displayed at least once.
2. Moving it to another folder will confuse the viewer who knows that he saved the entry and for some reason it is not there anymore. A solution for this is to send a notification to inform the viewer that his bookmark was deleted by another user.

Comment: Thanks @Ovidiu I think #2 is a good way. On this case Viewer don't have any idea if the manager deleted the document that the viewer save it as bookmark. Sending notification is also good so that the viewer will know that the current file is already deleted.

Comment: An animation could help: when the viewer looks at their list the first time after the manager archived the file, show the bookmark being moved to the “Unavailable” folder, then put a marker on that folder to indicate it has new content. After all, the file might become available again and then the bookmark would work, if I understand the scenario correctly, so it’s not wise to delete it too soon.